# How do I echo $command without breaking the layout

Tags: bash, echo, variable-expansion

I'm trying to do the following in a bash script:

```
com=`ssh host "ls -lh"`

echo $com
```

It works, but the echo will break the output (instead of getting all lines in a column, I get them all in a row).

If I do: `ssh host ls -lh` in the CLI it will give me the correct output and layout.

How can I preserve the layout when echoing a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
echo "$com"
```

The quotes make the shell not break the value up into "words", but pass it as a single argument to `echo`.

Comment: Oh c'mon, I was expecting something more "difficult".
But nonetheless, it worked.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put double quotes around $com:

```
com=`ssh host "ls -lh"`
printf "%s" $com | tr -dc '\n' | wc -c   # count newlines
printf "%s" "$com" | tr -dc '\n' | wc -c
echo "$com"
```