# How to expand ls -1 into a variable in Mac OSX terminal

Tags: macos, bash, unix, ls, variable-expansion

Using the bash shell in the Mac OS X terminal, I want to put inside a variable all the filenames in the current directory, with one name per line (basically, the output of ls -1).
However, if I do:

```
var=$(ls -1)
echo $var
```

Variable 'var' contains contains all the filenames, but on a single line, separated with spaces.
How can I fix this and get what I want.
More generally, what is the reason of this behavior? What is going on during the expansion of ls -1?

I realize that I could put what I want inside a file by doing the following, but I would rather achieve the same result with a variable.

```
ls -1 > var
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But why do you want to do this??? what are you going to do with this variable???

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations!

Although I simplified my question by using `ls`, I actually intend to use `stat`. My goal is to write a script that will
- look through all the files in a directory sorted by creation date
- identify all subgroups of files created less than x seconds apart
- make for each subgroup a subdirectory named after the creation date of the earliest file (YYMMDD-HHMMSS)
- move each subgroup into its subdirectory
Therefore, I need a table with two columns: file birth as Unix time (available in Mac OSX's version of `stat`) and file name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I echo $command without breaking the layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684216/how-do-i-echo-command-without-breaking-the-layout)

Answer (score 3):

Your command `var=$(ls -1)` works fine. Try `echo "$var"` (with double quotes).

In `echo $var`, bash is reading `$var` and passing each word in as an argument to `echo`. It treats spaces and line breaks the same way. Using double quotes causes bash to treat `$var` as a single argument, rather than reformatting it.

As mklement0 mentioned, the expansion of `$var` that happens here is called word splitting. Search for "Word Splitting" in `man bash` for more information. The `IFS` variable (also in `man bash`) controls what characters bash uses to perform word splitting.

Comment: Indeed; also worth mentioning that what happens here (splitting the value into words by whitespace and thus passing multiple arguments) is called _word splitting_, which is _one_ of the so-called _expansions_ that bash performs on unquoted variable references (search for `Word Splitting` in `man bash`, or, more generally, `EXPANSIONS`).